# Inequality constraints iOS for width

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

In the above picture (taken from RayWanderlich Auto layout tutorial on youtube) the blue view is pinned to the top and left and given two width constraints (one where `width >= 385` with priority 1000 and another width constraint `width = 385` with priority 999).

Since the constraint (`width >= 385`) is required how does it determine what the width should be? Since `>= 385` could mean any number of values. Or does this constraint not even come into play and it automatically goes to the lower priority constraint and set the width to 385?

Comment: Both constraints are satisfied with 385, so it has no reason to make it any larger than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width >= 385` constraint ensures the width is at least 385pt, but it doesn't actually provide a specific value (since any value >= 385 is valid). That's why there's the second constraint of `width = 385 @ 999`. This second constraint sets the width explicitly to 385. Its priority is 999, which means this constraint can be broken (but it has higher priority than e.g. the intrinsic content size constraints of views). The fact that this constraint is optional is why there's the second `width >= 385 @ 1000` constraint. The combination of these two constraints basically says "the width should be 385 if at all possible; if not possible, it's allowed to grow, but not to shrink".

Comment: So when would the `width >= 385` come into play then if that doesn't "actually provide a specific value (since any value >= 385 is valid)"?

Comment: @1290 It comes into play when the `width = 385 @ 999` constraint is broken. The two constraints together say "I really want this view to have a width of 385, but if that's not possible, then I require that it be >= 385, it absolutely cannot be less".

Comment: But there is no way that width = 385 can be broken since there is no right constraint so the view will expand as far to the right as possible (even if width is equal to 1000).

Comment: I'm assume that by the end of the tutorial you will have more than just a blue square on your screen. Presumably at some point something will be added to the view hierarchy that has the possibility of breaking the `width = 385 @ 999` constraint. Otherwise, why is that constraint even optional?